# MySQL: Select with SubQuery

Tags: mysql

I need help with a conditional select/sub query statement.

I have three tables, Tab1,Tab2 and Tab3. Each table has an ID column.

Tab1:

```
id | code
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 1
```

Tab2:

```
id | results
1  | data1
2  | data2
3  | data3
```

Tab3:

```
id | results
1  | data1
2  | data2
3  | data3
```

If Tab1.code is 1 for id1, than I want a select statement to return all results for id1 inside Tab2. If Tab1.code is 2 for id1, than I want all the results for id1 returned from Tab3.

I’ve been playing around with multiple sub queries and cannot get it to work.

Here is a fiddle with the basic structure: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=044b04ea153b15fc3ce17cefc292f6bc

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 2 sub-tables 2 and 3, you can try this solution:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.code, t2.results
FROM Tab1 t1
JOIN Tab2 t2
ON t1.code = 1 AND t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT t1.id, t1.code, t3.results
FROM Tab1 t1
JOIN Tab3 t3
ON t1.code = 2 AND t1.id = t3.id
```

Comment: Thanks! That works for my example. I am thinking I’ll have more than 2 sub tables for my actual build though. Any suggestions?

Comment: @John_Scully, by offering more legitimate context to the tables vs just constant secondary, tertiary tables, maybe a redesign MIGHT be a better option.  But with examples of Tab1, Tab2, Tab3 and no context, you might be getting an answer (which is ok as this one is), but your long-term may become a bit of a hinderance.

Comment: @DRapp, thanks for the feedback. Going forward I’ll try to provide better examples and if no one has a suggestion to handle additional tables than I’ll consider a rebuild.

Comment: @John_Scully, very well.  And if anything is considered private/confidential, you dont have to supply samples of LIVE data, just use test data to get the point across of intent.

Comment: Your problem is about dynamic query and I dont recommend this. You have another safe approach using LEFT JOIN